# Numbers not showing with list items in ordered list with display: inline-block; and text-overflow: ellipsis;

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make an ordered list of links but facing some problems, it is not showing numbers with list items when using display: inline-block; and text-overflow: ellipsis;

I have HTML

```
<ol>
    <li><a href="One">Link One One One One One One One One</a></li>
    <li><a href="Two">Link Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="Three">Link Three Three Three Three Three Three</a></li>
    <li><a href="Four">Link Four Four Four Four Four Four Four</a></li>
    <li><a href="Five">Link Five Five Five Five Five Five Five Five</a></li>
    <li><a href="Six">Link Six Six Six Six Six Six Six Six Six Six</a></li>
    <li><a href="Seven">Link Seven Seven Seven Seven Seven Seven Seven</a></li>
    <li><a href="Eight">Link Eight Eight Eight Eight Eight Eight Eight Eight</a></li>
    <li><a href="Nine">Link Nine Nine Nine Nine Nine Nine Nine Nine</a></li>
    <li><a href="Ten">Link Ten Ten Ten Ten Ten Ten Ten Ten Ten Ten</a></li>
</ol>
```

and css

```
ol li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 3px 12px 3px 12px;
  width: 200px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

JSfiddle is https://jsfiddle.net/3hebtbvz/

I need something like this
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a trick solving the lost number issue

*Side notes:*

- *A `li` is displayed as a `list-item` and when altered to `inline-block` the list style disappears*
- *[CSS counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters) could be another approach*

```css
ol li {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  margin-right: 30px;
}
ol li a {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<ol>
 <li><a href="One">Link One One One One One One One One</a></li>
 <li><a href="Two">Link Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two</a></li>
 <li><a href="Three">Link Three Three Three Three Three Three</a></li>
 <li><a href="Four">Link Four Four Four Four Four Four Four</a></li>
 <li><a href="Five">Link Five Five Five Five Five Five Five Five</a></li>
 <li><a href="Six">Link Six Six Six Six Six Six Six Six Six Six</a></li>
 <li><a href="Seven">Link Seven Seven Seven Seven Seven Seven Seven</a></li>
 <li><a href="Eight">Link Eight Eight Eight Eight Eight Eight Eight Eight</a></li>
 <li><a href="Nine">Link Nine Nine Nine Nine Nine Nine Nine Nine</a></li>
 <li><a href="Ten">Link Ten Ten Ten Ten Ten Ten Ten Ten Ten Ten</a></li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
            ol li {
              margin: 3px 12px 3px 12px;
              width: 200px;
              float:left;


            }

            ol{list-style-type: decimal;}
```

plunker url for reference-https://jsfiddle.net/Nagasai_Aytha/3hebtbvz/7/

Answer (score 1):

check this one.

https://jsfiddle.net/r29su84z/

```
ol li {
float: left;
width: 100px;
padding: 12px;
}

ol li a {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
width: 100%;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This JSFiddle produced rows of 4, keeping them numbered.

```
ol li {
  float: left;
  width: 130px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
ol li a {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Comment: Please read the question carefully, the Question is how to show numbers with list items of ordered list in above situation (when using display: inline-block; and text-overflow: ellipsis; )

Comment: @Syed: Did not see the numbers. One second.

Comment: @Syed: The numbers have been added.

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS:

```
ol{
padding: 20px; 
    list-style-type:decimal;

}
ol li {
float:left;
margin: 0 10px;
padding: 0 10px;
}
```

change `width:some_value%` to get number of links in a row.

https://jsfiddle.net/bhansa/3hebtbvz/3/

Comment: That doesn't quite do it, Syed wants them in rows of 4.